# AWS alarm on lamda availability using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

How can I create an AWS alarm based on lambda availability using terraform?
Terraform appears to be supporting only one metric type per alarm. For calculating availability we have to use both the Errors and Invocations metrics and cannot see how that can be done using Terraform.

PS: I can very easily get it done using the AWS console.

Comment: Did you try creating this directly from aws console?

Comment: Yes, that works.